# Help understanding logical inverters with NPN transistors

Tags: transistors, logic-gates

I built a circuit using an Arduino board that tests a logical inverter using NPN transistors. It works, but I'm trying to understand *why* it works.

[image: circuit diagram of a logical inverter]

The circuit consists of 2 push buttons:

1. Left most button on bottom board. This is the Inverter test.  When Pin7 is High, this button is disabled.  When Pin7 is Low, pressing this button will bring Pin2 Low (causing the onboard LED to illuminate)
2. Right most button on bottom board. This button brings Pin3 Low, which will toggle the state of Pin7.

The yellow wire is my input.  When Pin7 is high, the green LED is lit and the input to the right most NPN transistor is high.  **This is where I am struggling to understand what is happening.**  When the base is brought high (via Pin7 being high), current flows from the blue line, through the transistor, and back to ground, correct? Why doesn't current also flow through the orange wire? I guess, there is a tiny bit of current that flows through (the virtual multimeter shows ~5mV).

I guess my understanding of electricity is that if a wire is connected to power like the orange wire is through the resistor, then it should have a charge, right?  Why does the path through the transistor back to ground take priority when the base is high?  Why aren't both paths (blue and orange) energized at the same time?

The final question I have is around power consumption.  Will having these NPN transistors connected like this continuously draw current through the circuit? Should I be worried about the current draw if this circuit were battery powered?

If you'd like to explore the circuit, here is a link: https://www.tinkercad.com/things/925tzr3eQgD-logical-inverter?sharecode=HnrjlXw_c_-TWucWs_Mr8GE4MERS-WJjVebuuhAwDyk

**EDIT**

Here is the schematic. I need to get better at learning how to read these as well...  I don't know what the bottom circuits are showing, or why they are not connected to main circuit.

**Version B**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEBvww.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Original somewhat en-visibilised schematic reloaded.
Both are a bit hard to read but together may be useful.

VERSION A

[image]

Comment: A proper schematic is needed.

Comment: Can you draw a schematic? It saves everyone's time if you do it once, or everyone else that wants to answer your question must reverse-engineer your circuit implementation into a schematic.

Comment: W.r.t. for the request for a schematic, upon following the link to the tinkercad circuit, clicking "Simulate" and then select "Schematic View" in the top right get a normal schematic view.

Comment: Just updated with a schematic.  I also need to get better at reading them.

Comment: @joe_coolish While that is a schematic, it's simply all components put on a single line and a mess of wires routed between them. It is almost as difficult task to decipher what goes where than the original breadboard image.

Comment: @Justme, I will use the built in schematic designer and make a new one after I get the kids in bed.

Comment: Your old schematic and your new schematic do not represent the same circuit ... which of them is 'correct'? There are a number of thing in the new one which don't make a lot of sense to me ...

Comment: @brhans the current schematic should be the correct one, though I did leave out the LED, which was just for debugging purposes.  What doesn't make sense?  I apologize, I'm relatively new at this so I may have made a mistake when copying it over from the other diagram.

Comment: Collector of Q2 connected to GND. R1 & R2 simply connected between Vcc & GND (suspect R2 was supposed to be a pullup for GPIO3 ?)

Comment: @brhans Ah! You're right.  I fixed R1 and R2. For Q2, yes the collector is connected to ground. Is that not correct?

Comment: Also the R3/R4 resistors driving your transistors.

Comment: No, an NPN's collector is not usually grounded.

Comment: There are several differences between this schematic and the first one.  Assuming this one is more correct, where did this circuit come from?  And, what happened to the LED?

Comment: Where did you get the schematic from? Did you create it or ...? I have not spent time (yet() on comparing the 3 versions AS the final one is definitely wrong. eg Q2 collector cannot go to ground as it is an NPN and the polarity is wrong. || **THIS IS ESSENTIAL**: Rather than trying to critique the circuit it is better to ask how you arrived at it AND what you are trying to achieve. Can you use words to describe desired functionality. We can definitely help you to achieve what you want to do BUT it is pointless trying to critique the current circuit.

Answer (score 5):

The schematic is very difficult to read.

The T2 collector is tied to GND, so the it will not function as a normal transistor.  It is not clear what your intent is for this signal.

In the text you refer to "Pin7", but there is no pin 7 on the schematic.

UPDATE:

Here is a first pass at a re-drawn schematic.  I folded the two schematic sections into one.  Based on this schematic, two of my previous comments have been deleted.

[image]

NOTE:  When discussing the functions of individual components in a circuit, TinkerToy locations and wire colors are not good identifiers.  Be clear about which schematic you are referring to, and use the reference designators on that schematic.  For example, on my schematic the Q2 emitter is connected to the R4-R6 node.

UPDATE 2:

Here is a re-draw of the OP second schematic.

[image]

While there have been circuit changes around Q2, the connections around Q2 are very strange. Because the emitter is pulled up to Vcc, the transistor cannot conduct no matter what the base voltage is.

Also, it is not at all clear what the circuit is supposed to do.

Comment: Updated the OP with a schematic.

Comment: Q2 could be driven into reverse-active mode. Likely a mistake in the schematic, but it would still *sort of* work. Of course, with nothing actually connected to the output of this odd inverter, it's not exactly that useful.

Comment: The arrows in transistor symbols (and diodes, except Zeners) should point towards the more negative terminal of the power supply. (not necessarily be connected to the negative terminal, but headed that way).

Comment: The reverse breakdown base-emitter voltage usually is listed as 5 V or *minimum* for small-signal transistors.  Depending on that would not be reliable in a 5 V circuit.  This is almost certainly a schematic error.  Still no word on the source of the circuit.